# Why sql service is still running after uninstalling failover cluster instance?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover

The installation of sql server failover cluster instance didn't go well.
So I decided to remove whatever was installed and reinstall it again.

To to uninstall sql failover cluster instance went through `"Remove node from sql server failover cluster"`
Uninstall it. All good.

[image]

However I am still able to login to sql server configuration manager and see sql service is running.

[image]

So before trying to install FCI again, do I need to perform any other uninstallations?

Comment: This screenshot shows SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) running. This is not the SQL Server (database engine) Instance. Looks like you may have only uninstalled the database engine, but not all services & components.

Answer (score 1):

“ The installation of sql server failover cluster instance didn't go well. So I decided to remove whatever was installed and reinstall it again.”

That’s not a really good idea.  It looks like whatever went wrong left behind a mess.

“ So before trying to install FCI again, do I need to perform any other uninstallations?”

Yes.  First reinstall Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Reinstalling windows can be a problem for me, since I am not in charge of it. But I just was able to remove the rest of components through  "Add or Remove Programs". Do you think that would be a problem?

Comment: windows can return to s asve point before the mess started